# Is there any information about the Guild of Wonders beyond what's available in the Guide to Absalom?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, lore, golarion

I have a player interested in playing a CN rogue with a penchance for artwork trained by a guild of assassins. The Red Mantis seem too evil and don't work with his backstory for other reasons, but the [Guild of Wonders](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Guild_of_Wonders) sounds potentially promising. Is there any information about them beyond what's available in the *Guide to Absalom*? For example, do they feature in any PFS adventures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There is no additional information about them

There is a poison from *[Inner Sea Intrigue](https://paizo.com/products/btpy9l37?Pathfinder-Campaign-Setting-Inner-Sea-Intrigue)* (page 50), [Marvelous Fear Gas](https://www.aonprd.com/PoisonDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Marvelous%20fear%20gas), that is mentioned to be used by the Guild of Wonders.

> This poison is the creation of the Guild of Wonders in Absalom, whose members hunt down and intimidate their enemies.

We also know that the head of the guild, [Celedo of House Morilla](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Celedo_of_House_Morilla), has connections to the [Sovereign Court](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Sovereign_Court_(faction)), from Taldor. Yet, there is no mention of the guild in the [Taldor, the First Empire](https://paizo.com/products/btpy9wzs?Pathfinder-Campaign-Setting-Taldor-the-First-Empire) book.

Other than that, all the information we got is from *[Guide to Absalom](https://paizo.com/products/btpy86j8)*.

Answer (score 0):

### #07-05 - School of Spirits

In scenario *#07-05 - School of Spirits*, Grishan's notes indicate that the Guild of Wonders is connected to the Morilla family (and therefore to the Sovereign Court). His notes also indicate that the Aspis Consortium has hired the Guild of Wonders to assassinate several members of the Pathfinder Society over the years, a pattern that the Society had apparently failed to notice on their own.